# Java ME bittorrent client and mobile operator network compatibility

Tags: java, java-me, bittorrent

I'm interested in developing a Java ME BitTorrent client such as [MobTorrent](http://amorg.aut.bme.hu/projects/mobtorrent) to use in a Distance Education/OpenCourseWare suite for feature phones such as [Nokia Series 40](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Series_40) phones.

I've done some research into this idea, specifically on whether it would be viable to have feature phone users download ~41MB torrents of audio files through their mobile operator network. I've found that some mobile operators block torrent ports or ports outside of a very specific range needed for e-mail and web browsing.

So, I was wondering if anyone knows of a way to have the distributed, peer-to-peer file sharing benefits of torrents while not having to deal with blocked ports?

Do I use proxies? Do I figure out a way for torrents to use port 80 (http port)?

I want to use torrents because I need to avoid using dedicated servers, as most OpenCourseWare distributors use. The bandwidth costs of dedicated servers would be too expensive.

Thank you for your time. I appreciate any help that can be provided.

Comment: A Bittorrent client can run with any port you want, but it will probably not be able to accept incoming connections anyway when it runs inside the mobile network. On the other hand you can't really do much about the ports of the other users in the swarm without tunneling all the traffic except when they all run clients that are under your control.

Comment: @x4u: Thanks for your reply. Not being able to accept incoming connections might be a problem. Is there anyway around that? Perhaps by using a server as a middle man, somehow? And about the ports of other users, I think if everyone in the swarm were using my torrent client, it might be possible.

Comment: @x4u: On using a server as a middle man, a Google search has come up with [TCP Hole Punching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TCP_hole_punching) as a possible idea. I wonder, if I use TCP hole punching and set the ports to 80 (http traffic), would I be able to get around the port blocking techniques used by the mobile operator network? This might mean that users can't browse the internet at the same time that they're torrenting.

Comment: Many mobile networks do not support listening for incoming connections on the connected devices. The devices often don't even get a *real* IP address but something that is NATed by the network provider and you must also be prepared to deal with transparent proxies in these networks that filter all traffic. Hole punching could work in some cases (not with proxies) but is very tricky (i.e. unreliable) and you need to operate a mediator server for it. So you could as well just rent a server somewhere where traffic is cheap and route everything through it.

Comment: Maybe it's too early to consider using torrents on a mobile operator's network. I think I'll settle for torrents when the mobile phone is connected to a WiFi network.